# Prepare multidimensional array for mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am retrieving a multidimensional array from an external API and I need to store the results within my mysql table but I cannot figure out how to do it. I have tried several options but cannot make any headway.

Here is the array which comes from the API:

```
Array
(
    [per_page] => 100
    [total] => 69
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total_time] => 374
                    [href] => https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/######
                    [custom_variables] => Array
                        (
                            [ref] => 38i7zw
                        )

                    [ip_address] => 198.x.x.x
                    [id] => 4917
                    [logic_path] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [date_modified] => 2016-08-18T10:04:26+00:00
                    [response_status] => completed
                    [custom_value] => 
                    [pages] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 249
                                    [questions] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 247
                                    [questions] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 985
                                                    [answers] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [choice_id] => 103
                                                                )

                                                            [1] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [choice_id] => 107
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 985
                                                    [answers] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [choice_id] => 1037
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 249
                                    [questions] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )
```

What I would like to do is insert some of the array elements into the table as follows:

```
ref     |  survey_id  |  question_id  |  answer_id
38i7zw  |  4917       |  985          |  103
```

This means that I need to map a few elements as follows:

- "survey_id": "id" located after "data"
- "question_id": "id" located after "questions"
- "answer_id" is the "choice_id"

My assumption is that I need to convert the array into the format below, after which I can insert the data into my table - but I cannot figure out how to do it:

```
array (
  [0] => [
       'ref' => 'abc',
       'survey_id' = '123',
       'question_id' => '234',
       'answer_id' => '345'
    ],
  [1] => [
       ...
```

Any help is most appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Try something like this                                     foreach($array as $key => $value){
  if(is_array($value)){
    foreach($value as $key => $value){
      echo $key." ".$value."<br>";
    }
  }
  echo "<br>";
}   and add sql insert inside

Comment: I wish the solution was so simple. See below for a class I had to create

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing, here is my answer - I hope somebody else finds this useful (I am using the Yii2 framework).

The class will convert an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [per_page] => 100
    [total] => 69
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total_time] => 374
                    [href] => https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/######
                    [custom_variables] => Array
                        (
                            [ref] => 38i7zw
                        )

                    [ip_address] => 198.x.x.x
                    [id] => 4917
                    [logic_path] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [date_modified] => 2016-08-18T10:04:26+00:00
                    [response_status] => completed
                    [custom_value] => 
                    [pages] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 249
                                    [questions] => Array
                                        (
                                        )
```

Into something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [answer_id] => 10375872133
            [question_id] => 985997023
            [question_text] => Who was the contact?
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [answer_id] => 10375872147
            [question_id] => 985997023
            [question_text] => Which group did you use?
        )
```

The beauty of this solution is that it doesn't matter how deep the array is or if the columns do not exist in every nested array - the Class will consistently return the data in the same format.

Here is how to use it:

1) instantiate the class and pass the array to it:

```
$obj = new ArrayToolkit($array)
```

2) Print a list of elements which exist in the array. The elements are returned in a "dot-separated" format and act as an indexing system.

```
$list = $obj->getListOfKeys();
echo "<pre>" . print_r($list, 1) . "</pre>";
```

The list will look something like this (the number on the right is the number of occurrences of that element within the array you passed to the class) :

```
Array
(
    [data.total_time] => 69
    [data.href] => 69
    [data.custom_variables.ref] => 69
    [data.ip_address] => 69
    [data.id] => 69
    [data.date_modified] => 69
    [data.response_status] => 69
    [data.custom_value] => 69
    [data.analyze_url] => 69
    [data.pages.id] => 1311
```

2) define and rename the elements you want returned:

```
$obj->keysToFind([
            'answer_id'=>'data.pages.questions.answers.choice_id',
            'question_id'=>'data.pages.questions.id',
            'question_text' => 'placeholder'
        ]);
```

In the example above, the Class will return three elements: answer_id, question_id, question_text

Couple interesting points about this function:

- It will rename the element into something more suitable for you
- You can insert placeholders even though you know the data doesn't exist
  in the array
- You can select which elements you want returned, it will
  not return all elements if you don't need them.
- The output is consistent, even if one sub-array does not have all the elements

4) Get the data back:

```
$arr = $obj->target([
  'answer_id'=>'data.pages.questions.answers.choice_id',
]);
```

The "target" is important: This is the key/value pair you most care about. The function is searching through the array to find this key. Once it finds the key, it returns the value and then, all the other data you requested (ie the parent elements that you want).

Note, it doesn't return the child elements, only the parent elements but if you have a child element in the "keys to find" it will be null. For this reason, the target should be the deepest child element but does not have to be. You may wonder why I would design it this way but I have done so because the function allows you to ADD another target.

For example, if you now ran:

```
 $arr = $obj->target([
  'question_id'=>'data.pages.questions.id',
]);
```

The results would be added to your existing output. This is very important for badly designed arrays (as is the case for the array I am working with).

In the end, you get a nice clean array for batch inserts!

Hope this helps. Here is the code

PS: the reference to Toolkit::PrintObj() is equivalent to

```
echo "<pre>" . print_r($var, 1) . "</pre>";



<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

/**
 * Class ArrayToolkit
 * @package app\models
 */
class ArrayToolkit extends \yii
{

    // This holds the data for this class
    public $model = array();

    /**
     * model constructor.
     * @param $array
     */
    function __construct($array)
    {
        $this->getArrayIndex($array);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getListOfKeys()
    {
        //Toolkit::printObject($this->model['list_of_keys']);
        return $this->model['list_of_keys'];
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getIndex()
    {
        return $this->model['index'];
    }


    // This is the heart of the function. "KeysToFind" is the list of keys it will search for
    // These keys will allways be in the same order and will exist even if a particular key is empty
    // This is needed for batch inserts into mysql
    public function keysToFind($arr)
    {
        $this->model['keys_to_find']['all'] = $arr;
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $this->model['keys_to_find']['temp'][$key] = null;
        }
    }

    // this function is the function which kicks off the search to populate the data
    // this function is additive! ie new results are added to old results. To clear the cache,
    // you need to clear $this->model['mysql_array']
    public function target($target)
    {
        $this->model['keys_to_find']['target']['name'] = key($target);
        $this->model['keys_to_find']['target']['key'] = array_values($target)[0];
        $this->buildMysqlArray();
        return $this->model['mysql_array'];
    }


    /**
     * This function will create an array of elements suitable for mysql insert
     * User simply loops over the array and inserts into table
     */
    private function buildMysqlArray()
    {
        // name = the new name assigned by user
        // key = string eg pages.questions.answers.id
        // index is the indexing id eg [0.12] or [0.1.2.3]
        // levelCount is the number of levels within the index
        // For example [0] = 1 level, [0.0] = 2 levels, [0.0.0] = 3 levels

        // Target is the value the user is looking for
        // For example: The answer ID
        $target_key = $this->model['keys_to_find']['target']['key'];
        $target_name = $this->model['keys_to_find']['target']['name'];
        $target_levelCount = $this->model['index'][$target_key]['index_levelCount'];
        $target_array = $this->model['index'][$target_key]['members'];

        // Other is all the other supporting values (typically foreign keys)
        // For example: Survey ID, Question ID etc

        $other = $this->model['keys_to_find']['all'];

        // Toolkit::printObject($this->model);
        // loop through the target array eg pages.questions.answers.id
        foreach ($target_array as $target_index => $target_value) {
            $temp = $this->model['keys_to_find']['temp']; // this ensures that all keys are present in the output
            // for each answer, assign the value
            $temp[$target_name] = $target_value;

            // now loop through all the other keys the users wants
            if ($other !== null) {
                foreach ($other as $other_name => $other_key) {
                    if (isset($this->model['index'][$other_key]['members']) && $other_key != $target_key) {
                        // "members" is the array of answers or pages etc
                        $other_array = $this->model['index'][$other_key]['members'];
                        $other_levelCount = $this->model['index'][$other_key]['index_levelCount'];
                        // if the question_id is 1.2.3.4 then it has 4 levels.
                        // however a page might be on 1.2.3 (ie 3 levels)
                        // To find the page for our question, we simply shorten the question index to the same number of levels
                        // ie 1.2.3.4 becomes 1.2.3
                        // and now we can easily find the page by using the key: page['1.2.3']
                        if ($other_levelCount < $target_levelCount) {
                            $indexToFind = substr($target_index, 0, $this->strposX($target_index, ".", $other_levelCount));
                        } else {
                            $indexToFind = $target_index;
                        }
                        if (isset($other_array[$indexToFind])) {
                            $temp[$other_name] = $other_array[$indexToFind];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $this->model['mysql_array'][] = $temp;
            $temp = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $array
     * @param string $prefix
     * @param bool $recursive
     * @return array
     */
    private function getArrayIndex($array, $prefix = '', $recursive = false)
    {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) { // $value is another array - we will need to do a recursive loop
                if (is_int($key)) { // incremental key eg [0] or [1] etc
                    // The format is as follows:
                    // pages[0]['questions'][1]['id'][2] becomes...
                    // 0.1.2-pages.questions.id
                    // With each loop of this function, I explode the string on "-" and then add the new index
                    // 0.1.2- becomes 0.1.2.3-
                    if (strpos($prefix, "-")) {
                        $arr = explode("-", $prefix);
                        $result = $result + $this->getArrayIndex($value, $arr[0] . "." . $key . '-' . $arr[1], true);
                    } else {
                        $result = $result + $this->getArrayIndex($value, $key . '-' . $prefix, true);
                    }
                } else {// key is not an integer. It is a string  eg "questions". Append it to the $prefix
                    $result = $result + $this->getArrayIndex($value, $prefix . $key . '.', true);
                }
            } else { // $value is not an array, it is the actual value
                if (strpos($prefix, "-")) {
                    $temp = explode("-", $prefix);
                    $this->model['index'][$temp[1] . $key]['index_levelCount'] = substr_count($temp[0], ".") + 1;
                    $this->model['index'][$temp[1] . $key]['members'][$temp[0]] = $value;
                }
                $result[$prefix . $key] = $value;
            }
        }
        // CLEANUP:
        // We don't want to process every recursive loop, only the final array being returned.
        if ($recursive === false) { // This is the final return
            $list_of_keys = array();
            foreach ($result as $str => $val) {
                if (strpos($str, "-")) {
                    $temp = explode("-", $str);
                    if (isset($list_of_keys[$temp[1]])) {
                        $list_of_keys[$temp[1]] = $list_of_keys[$temp[1]] + 1;
                    } else {
                        $list_of_keys[$temp[1]] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            $this->model['list_of_keys'] = $list_of_keys;
        }

        return $result;
    }


    /**
     * @param $haystack
     * @param $needle
     * @param $number
     * @return bool|int
     * This function will get the n'th occurrence of the needle
     */
    private function strposX($haystack, $needle, $number)
    {
        if ($number == '1') {
            return strpos($haystack, $needle);
        } elseif ($number > '1') {
            return strpos($haystack, $needle, $this->strposX($haystack, $needle, $number - 1) + strlen($needle));
        } else {
            $this->model['ERR'][] = ['strposX' => 'Value for parameter $number is out of range'];
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```